# How to set MySQL JDBC parameters in django-jython?

Tags: mysql, django, jdbc, jython

How can I set JDBC parameters when using Jython? I'm running Django using django-jython.

Comment: https://pythonhosted.org/django-jython/database-backends.html

Comment: @Newtt I saw that, but I'm looking for a way to set JDBC paramters, which are at the end of JDBC URI.

Comment: It looks like the only way to set the parameters is to creat JNDI configuration.